# Disable pylint missing docstring warning for protected classes

Tags: python, pylint

Is it possible to disable pylint warnings related to missing docstring within a module for protected (starting with underscore character) classes only? There is a possibility to disable warnings for method or classes that fulfill a certain regex precondition(by default everything which starts with _ is omited) but what in cases a given protected class contains non-protected method?